# Javascript - how to use a variable as a function *and* an object literal

Tags: javascript, function, methods, object-literal

I've seen people use a variable as both an object and a function like so:

```
myClass();
```

and

```
myClass.myMethod();
```

How do they do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Functions are objects in Javascript so you can set properties (like other functions or objects on them):

```
function myClass() {
    //blah blah
}

myClass.myMethod = function() {
    //your other function
}

myClass.myMethod();
```

Comment: And thus, jQuery has become simple to understand.